# 'Location'(geolocation) support in OS versions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is 'Location'(geolocation) native api supported in all iphnoe os versions from iphone 2.o to ios 4+ ? Is there any documentation to get the list of all API's and the supporting  versions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, its called core Location Framework:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497) is the apple documentation about CoreLocation.